# Swift - Storing and retrieving data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

My doubt is this: how can I store some data (strings and images, for example) in the application and then, later, retrieve these data **properly**? 
I've read some stuff about it but I didn't quite understand (call me whatever you want u.u).

My idea is that I have some ViewControllers, and, in each one, I'm inserting some data, like names, images, texts, and I want one final ViewController to retrieve all these data, when I tap a cell. I have almost everything done, except that I don't know how to retrieve all these data in the last ViewController. How should I do it? Delegates pattern? Using CoreData?

**EDIT**

I have 4 ViewControllers. The first one has a tableView that will store some recipe name. The second one, I will text the name of the recipe and pick an image from photoLibrary. This second ViewController has two segues: one to the third ViewController, in which I'll text some ingredients for the recipe; and the fourth one, in which I'll text the recipe's HowToDo. When I text all ingredients and the HowToDo the app goes to the second ViewController, then when I press "ADD" it goes to the first ViewController, and the cell receives the name of the recipe. Then, when I tap the cell, it goes to a fifth ViewController, which will show the details (name, image, ingredients listed in a tableView and the HowToDo).

My doubt is: How can I retrieve all the data from those ViewControllers?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` are most likely what you're looking for. Here's an example: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30331820/2108547) and the [Apple Doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Comment: This question is too broad, and without enough detail. You need to provide some information about your controller hierarchy, and also on whether you want this data to persist between launches of the app.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot be more specific than that cause I'm not able to post images yet :( I'm trying as Daniel Storm said.

Comment: @DanielStorm I don't know if NSUserDefaults is what I'm after. I read some people say that it doesn't work for storing images. What do you think? Should I follow some CoreData tutorial ?

Comment: What I'm looking for is some way to store the information set in each ViewController (image, name, text and a tableview) and being able to retrieve this data in the last VC. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 options:

1) NSUserDefaults - Good for small amounts of data

2) Store on file system using NSArchiver.

3) SqlLite - Good for larger amounts of data.

4) CoreData - Stores object graphs. Very advanced but steep learning curve.

For details on all these methods watch the persistence part of the following video:
https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/961180099/feed

Comment: I am storing small amount of data in each cell, but it will come a time that it will have too many cells with infomation stored, so I think NSUserDefaults is not good in this case. I think CoreData is really the solution. Thanks for the video-link. Tomorrow I'll try and give you a feedback!

Comment: I think that sqlite fits your use case. But using sqlite with swift is tricky. So maybe you should just try Core Data.

Comment: I managed to save some text using CoreData but I can't find a way to store an image picked from photo library. I read that it has to be converted to NSDate but I don't know how to properly do it. Any idea?