# How to save a high score with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im starting to learn how to code and i have no clue how to save the score to stay as a high score. any help will be appreciated! i already tried and tried but i can't manage to get it right. at this point i don't know what to do.

```
class Game: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let Ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Red.png")
var QuitOption = SKLabelNode()
var ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var timesecond = Int(60)
var locked = false
var loseOption = SKLabelNode()
var scorePoints = SKLabelNode()
var score = Int()
var highScore = SKLabelNode()
let whiteBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fingerPointingDown.png")


struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let Ball: UInt32 = 0b1
    static let whiteBall: UInt32 = 0b10
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor() // background for the display

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    let SceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    SceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = SceneBody

    scorePoints = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Noteworthy-Light")
    scorePoints.text = "0"
    scorePoints.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    scorePoints.fontSize = 35
    scorePoints.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*1 - 120)
    scorePoints.name = "Points"
    scorePoints.hidden = true

    addChild(scorePoints)

    Ball.size = CGSize(width: 82, height: 82)
    Ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.1 - 60)
    Ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 41)
    Ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Ball.physicsBody?.density = 10
    Ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
    Ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    Ball.name = "Ball"
    Ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    Ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
    Ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.whiteBall
    Ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.whiteBall

    self.addChild(Ball)

    QuitOption.text = "Quit"
    QuitOption.fontName = "Noteworthy-Light"
    QuitOption.fontColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
    QuitOption.fontSize = 35
    QuitOption.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 - 160, y: self.frame.size.height*1 - 110)
    QuitOption.name = "Quit"

    addChild(QuitOption)

    ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Noteworthy-Light")
    ScoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
    ScoreLabel.fontSize = 35                 // The + will move it to the right side and - to the left side for more accuracy.
    ScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 + 160, y: self.frame.size.height/1 - 115) // position of ScoreLabelNode
    ScoreLabel.name = "Score+"
    ScoreLabel.hidden = false

    self.addChild(ScoreLabel)

    whiteBall.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 55)
    whiteBall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.8 - 30)
    whiteBall.name = "whiteBall"
    whiteBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.whiteBall
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
    whiteBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball

    self.addChild(whiteBall)


}

// Making the ball jump after user touches ball

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


    if (node.name == "Quit"){

        let myScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        myScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
        self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)

    }

    if (node.name == "Ball"){

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {


            Ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
            Ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 450))

        }

    }

    if(!self.locked){

        self.locked = true

        var actionrun = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
        var actionwait = SKAction.runBlock({

            self.timesecond--

            if self.timesecond == 60 {self.timesecond = 0}

            self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.timesecond)"

            if (self.timesecond == 0){

                let myScene = WT(size: self.size)
                myScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
                let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
                self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)

            }
        })

        let loopAction = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([actionwait, actionrun]), count: 60)

        ScoreLabel.runAction(loopAction, withKey: "scoreAction")


    }

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.Ball | PhysicsCategory.whiteBall {

        score++

        scorePoints.text = "Score: \(score)"
        scorePoints.hidden = false

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` will be the easiest solution. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30331820/2108547).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: "high_score")
NSUserDefaults.synchronize() // must be used to save
```

You can then load the score when needed

```
let highScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("high_score")
```

You can access NSUserDefaults from anywhere, saving and loading as needed.

If you have more global player state, create an object for it and you could serialize the object by making it conform to NSCoding protocol.

You would need to implement the encode and decode functions, that save aand load your object's properties.